# How to Raspberry pi main memory (Read and write)

Tags: memory, raspberry-pi, ram, raspbian

I want to access raspberry pi's main memory, I have learned all basic stuff related to the device from Baking Pi website. So far i was working on registers, but now I want to have access to device's main memory. The problem is that i do not know the base address of main memory from where i can start working reading and writing.
I have made a lot of search but Google always points towards GPIO and other stuff.
If someone can please provide me the base address or any web link from where i could know how to continue, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the bcm2835 data sheet?
http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.raspberrypi.org%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2012%2F02%2FBCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf&ei=QBpSU_m_Jqan8gGV-YDoBQ&usg=AFQjCNHP-j0e8vqALoieF5shMbgPaYcYEg&sig2=bVJ9mqBrcV4xH3FWAfhJGQ&bvm=bv.65058239,d.aWw